# Different number of outliers with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, boxplot

Can somebody explain to me why I get a different number of `outliers` with the normal [boxplot](/questions/tagged/boxplot) command and with the `geom_boxplot` of [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2)?
Here you have an example:

```
x <- c(280.9, 135.9, 321.4, 333.7, 0.2, 71.3, 33.0, 102.6, 126.8, 194.8, 35.5, 
       107.3, 45.1, 107.2, 55.2, 28.1, 36.9, 24.3, 68.7, 163.5, 0.8, 31.8, 121.4, 
       84.7, 34.3, 25.2, 101.4, 203.2, 194.1, 27.9, 42.5, 47.0, 85.1, 90.4, 103.8, 
       45.1, 94.0, 36.0, 60.9, 97.1, 42.5, 96.4, 58.4, 174.0, 173.2, 164.1, 92.1, 
       41.9, 130.2, 94.7, 121.5, 261.4, 46.7, 16.3, 50.7, 112.9, 112.2, 242.5, 140.6, 
       112.6, 31.2, 36.7, 97.4, 140.5, 123.5, 42.9, 59.4, 94.5, 37.4, 232.2, 114.6, 
       60.7, 27.8, 115.5, 111.9, 60.1)
data <- data.frame(x)
boxplot(data$x)
ggplot(data, aes(y=x)) + geom_boxplot()
```

With the `boxplot` command I get the plot below with `4 outliers`. 
[image]

And with `ggplot2` I get the plot below with `5 outliers`. 
[image]

Comment: Look at the ylimits. You're essentially zooming in.

Comment: given that both plots show data from 200-300, and that's where the extra outlier is, this isn't a zoom issue

Comment: ggplot2 and base boxplot use same range (1.5), but do they use same way to calculate quantiles?

Comment: `(boxplot(data$x))` shows that its upper hinge is at 122.5, not 122.0 as suggested by `quantile(data$x)`. This would put the end of the whisker at 242.5, which is above the 241.25 point. @dww's excellent answer demonstrates a way to mitigate this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ggplot and boxplot use slightly different methods to calculate the statistics. From `?geom_boxplot` we can see

> The lower and upper hinges correspond to the first and third quartiles
>   (the 25th and 75th percentiles). This differs slightly from the method
>   used by the boxplot() function, and may be apparent with small
>   samples. See boxplot.stats() for for more information on how hinge
>   positions are calculated for boxplot().

You can get ggplot to use `boxplot.stats` if you want the same results

```
# Function to use boxplot.stats to set the box-and-whisker locations  
f.bxp = function(x) {
  bxp = boxplot.stats(x)[["stats"]]
  names(bxp) = c("ymin","lower", "middle","upper","ymax")
  bxp
}  

# Function to use boxplot.stats for the outliers
f.out = function(x) {
  data.frame(y=boxplot.stats(x)[["out"]])
}
```

To use those functions in ggplot:

```
ggplot(data, aes(0, y=x)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data=f.bxp, geom="boxplot") + 
  stat_summary(fun.data=f.out, geom="point")
```

[image]

If you want to replicate the statistics that ggplot uses natively, these are explained in `?geom_boxplot` as follows:

> **ymin** = lower whisker = smallest observation greater than or equal to
>   lower hinge - 1.5 * IQR
>
> **lower** = lower hinge, 25% quantile
>
> **notchlower** = lower edge of notch = median - 1.58 * IQR / sqrt(n)
>
> **middle** = median, 50% quantile
>
> **notchupper** = upper edge of notch = median + 1.58 * IQR / sqrt(n)
>
> **upper** = upper hinge, 75% quantile
>
> **ymax** = upper whisker = largest observation less than or equal to upper
>   hinge + 1.5 * IQR

We can calculate these accordingly:

```
y = sort(x)
iqr = quantile(y,0.75) - quantile(y,0.25)
ymin = y[which(y >= quantile(y,0.25) - 1.5*iqr)][1]
ymax = tail(y[which(y <= quantile(y,0.75) + 1.5*iqr)],1)
lower = quantile(y,0.25)
upper = quantile(y,0.75)
middle = quantile(y,0.5)

ggplot(data, aes(y=x)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=c(ymin)), color='red', linetype='dashed') +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=c(ymax)), color='red', linetype='dashed') +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=c(lower)), color='red', linetype='dashed') +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=c(upper)), color='red', linetype='dashed') +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=c(middle)), color='red', linetype='dashed')
```

[image]

We can also extract these statistics directly from a ggplot object using `ggplot_build`

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(y=x)) + geom_boxplot() 
ggplot_build(p)$data[1:5]

#   ymin lower middle upper  ymax 
# 1  0.2  42.5  93.05   122 232.2
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the stats from the geom_boxplot like in boxplot.stats()?

Comment: Thanks @dww for answering so quickly. Just one thing, in the computation of ymin you must use >=, and in the computation of ymax <=, must'n you?